# Codemirror fromTextArea error: options.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I actually have a completely different error related to hidden tabs but when I have come to create a simplified fiddle example I am getting this error:

```
Error: TypeError: options.value is undefined
Source File: http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js
Line: 55
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gWZeQ/

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("test1"));  

<texarea id="test1" name="test1">function test() { 
    return false;
}</texarea>
```

Comment: Why are you defining a function in between a textarea?

Comment: Because he's using CodeMirror, which is for editing code in the browser. That's the code he's editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work, according to the docs it's fine.

However, here's a code that works ok :)

```
var myTextArea = document.getElementById("test1"),
var editor = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
  myTextArea.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, myTextArea);
}, {value: myTextArea.innerHTML});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/gWZeQ/1/

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 3):

The reason your example does not work is that you have a `texarea` element rather than a `texTarea`, and those do not have a `value` property.

Comment: Wonderful answer... It should be the accepted one, indeed it is inexplicable how the mistake could have been done either in the opening or in the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

As Marijn said, in this case that your element is texarea.

If thats just a typo and its still not working, make sure that the dom element exists before trying to initialize CodeMirror.